# How To Create a Session Id and Security Token In Amadeus Web Servics

Tags: web-services, soap, amadeus

I want to create a Air plane search engine using Amadeus web services. So, Now I have Amadeus WSDL file and XSD files. Then I tried with SoapUI with these files. But, now I want to provide Session Id and Security Token with the headers.

How can I get the Session id and Security Token ??

PS - I am very new to this thing. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a stateless header and hit the Amadeus endpoint. By which you will get token, session info.

If you are using in php you can download the code from GitHub and check your require function is implemented or not

[Link](https://github.com/amabnl/amadeus-ws-client) of GitHub